# MongoDB count fields with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

in my collection i have an document that contains following array (simplyfied):

```
 notifications: [
    {
       message: "i am an message",
       readed: false
    },
    {
       message: "i am an message",
       readed: false
    },
    {
       message: "i am an message",
       readed: true
    },
    {
       message: "i am an message",
       readed: true
    }
 ]
```

I want to count all fields with `readed:false` so that is my expected result:

```
{
   unreaded_messages: 2
}
```

I have tried to add an field and to map over the notification array and to add all unreaded elements. after that i wanted to get the size with `$size` so i get an number. But it doesnt worked how i expected.

```
{
$addFields: {
  unreaded_messages: {
    $map: {
      input: "$notification",
      in: {
        check: {
          $eq: [
            "$$this.readed",
            false
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "unreaded_messages": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$notification",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": ["$$this.readed", false]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```